# Angular 6 - AnguarFire - query a collection using multiple document fields

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I use AngularFire & Cloud Firestore in my project and I need to make a query with multiple conditions(where) to a collection.

I tried to use this code but it's ignoring the second condition.

```
 this.itemCollection = this.afs.collection<Item>('items', ref => {

 return ref
         .where('size', '==', 'large')
         .where('brand', '==', 'some-brand')
 })
 this.items = this.itemCollection.valueChanges();
```

What am I doing wrong, how do I apply multiple conditions in AngularFire?

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs to be:

```
this.itemCollection = this.afs.collection<Item>('items', ref => ref.where('size', '==', 
'large').where('brand', '==', 'some-brand'))
return this.items = this.itemCollection.valueChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Queries on different fields using multiple `where` clauses are **invalid** [[1](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/b91cd5a84c/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md#invalid-query-combinations)][[2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries)].
This is not true => multiple `where` queries are supported by firebase when the query type is the same, eg "==" && "==". [3](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) only where you mix types eg "==" && "=>" will firebase reject it.

However, check this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26701282/4000674) to another questions on SO: [*Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26701282/4000674).